# Why spark returns different value for unix_timestamp function?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, amazon-emr

One of my Hive table has a column which has dates in `String` format. After loading that table into Spark I am converting those dates to unix timestamp format using `unix_timestamp()` function. I am getting different values for same date and same date format when I use it in different Spark environments.

Here is the sample date for one of the row `2017-08-04 03:26:51.756658` and date format passed to `unix_timestamp()` function is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS`

Actual command used is as follows:

```
val baseWithUnixTime = base.withColumn("ZZOTIMSTP", 
$"ZZOTIMSTP".cast(TimestampType))
.withColumn("ZZOTIMSTP", $"ZZOTIMSTP".cast(TimestampType))
.withColumn("unix_time", unix_timestamp($"ZZOTIMSTP", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"))
```

When I execute above command in my local Spark, for this `2017-08-04 03:26:51.756658` value I get `1501813611` as unix timestamp.
When I execute same command in EMR Spark cluster, I get `1501817211` value.

If I try the same thing in Hive using `select unix_timestamp("2017-08-04 03:26:51.756658", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");` command, I get `1501817967` this value.

To summarize, Environment wise results are as follows:

```
+---------------------------+-----------+
| local Spark (version 2.2) | 1501813611|
+---------------------------|-----------+
| Spark in EMR (version 2.1)| 1501817211|
+---------------------------|-----------+
| Hive                      | 1501817967|
+---------------------------|-----------+
```

I wonder which is giving me true value? Why Hive and Spark give different values for same function and same set of values?

Comment: For the Spark environments it seems like timezone differences. Verify using `select printf('%1$TZ,%1$Tz',current_timestamp) as tz;`. Regarding Hive I'm a little puzzled here. Please verify you have used the same timestamp that you have used for Spark.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Spark settings:

```
set ('spark.sql.session.timeZone', 'GMT+XX')
```

XX - desired value